# How do Supernatural Transformation and Meta-Spell-Like-Abilities Feat work together?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, feats, special-abilities

Let's say a Pit Fiend turn its own spell-like ability, fireball, into a supernatural ability with the feat "Supernatural Transformation".

And before doing so, he has also taken Quicken Spell-Like Ability (Fireball).

Since the Fireball is now Supernatural Ability, does that mean he can no longer quicken it, and the feat Quicken Spell-Like Ability (Fireball) becomes completely useless for him now? Or can he still quicken it since it is originally a spell-like ability?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## "Oops!" says the pit fiend

If a [pit fiend](http://dndsrd.net/monstersDtoDe.html#pit-fiend-devil) doesn't have the spell-like ability *fireball* anymore because that pit fiend took the feat **Supernatural Transformation** ([*fireball*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsFtoG.html#fireball)) (*Savage Species* 39) so as to change its spell-like ability into a supernatural ability, then that pit fiend made an unwise choice when it earlier picked the feat [**Quicken Spell-like Ability**](http://dndsrd.net/monsterFeats.html#quicken-spell-like-ability) (*fireball*) (*Monster Manual* 304). It can't apply to a supernatural ability a feat that must be applied to a spell-like ability.

The pit fiend would need to take something like the feat **Quicken Supernatural Ability** (that doesn't exist in the official corpus so far as I'm aware) to employ its supernatural ability *fireball* as a swift action.

A pit fiend, though, has the spell-like ability [*wish*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsTtoZ.html#wish) usable once per year, so if a pit fiend did make such a mistake—taking the Quicken Spell-like Ability (*fireball*) feat then obviating it by taking later the Supernatural Transformation (*fireball*) feat—, then (at worst) it could employ a *wish* to fix it.